# How to check if field ID exists?

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to write a code that will look if certain text field (and drop-down boxes) IDs exists.

I'm working with a page where, depending on what options are selected, the available boxes will be changed. For example, starting with the blank page, "form" and "comments" may appear or "Division" and "Comments" may be present.

I have all of the field ID names, and I know how to grab the value from them.

My question is: how would I write the If statement to see if it exists?

Comment: Let's look into your code please for the better understanding what do you have already achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're still working on an HTA, something like this should work:

```
id = "Division"
If window.document.getElementById(id) Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "Element not found."
Else
  MsgBox "Element found."
End If
```

Comment: Awesome, this looks like what I'm looking for thanks! I'll plug this in and see if it works.

Comment: Just adding some 2 cents worth:              if Not(document.getelementbyid("ThisYear") is nothing) then
                Set SelList = document.getelementbyid("ThisYear")
                sYear = SelList.value
            End if